# Different ways of ordering 6 pizzas from 3 possible pizza options

Tags: combinatorics

A Pizzeria offers 3 possible Pizza Options( Margherita, Pepperoni and Prosciutto ). A person called and ordered 6 pizzas. In how many different ways can this order be made?

Ps: I found this problem only with the answer, which by the way is 28, but i do not have a clue on how to approach the solution. Thanks for the Help in advance :)

Comment: Alternative approach: Number of non-negative integer solutions to $~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6.~$ For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 4):

Choosing any number of a particular pizza is represented by the generating function

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$$

where, if we want four pizzas, we choose the coefficient of $x^4$.

For three pizzas, this becomes

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = 1 + 3x + 6x^2 + \dots +  \binom{k+2}{2}x^k + \dots$$

As we want the coefficient of $x^6$, this is $\binom{8}{2}=28$.

Comment: Generally, for an arbitrary $n$ quantities of pizzas ordered, and $t$ different types of pizzas, what would be the generating function for the number of unique orders as a function of $n$ and $t$?

Comment: @James; using my working for the general case, it is $\binom{n+t-1}{t-1}$. A simple visual aid for this is to imagine $n$ blank pizzas and $t-1$ dividers, as $t-1$ dividers create $t$ partitions. Then shuffle them for $\binom{n+t-1}{t-1}$ arrangements.

Comment: thank you. In the OP's case of 6 pizzas of 3 different types, I see $\begin{pmatrix} . & . & . & . & . & . \end{pmatrix}$ pizzas and therefore $\binom{7}{2}$ ways of partitioning them into 3 types $\begin{pmatrix} | & . & | & . & | & . & | & . & | & . & | & . & |\end{pmatrix}$, but i can't quite see how would we get $\binom{8}{2}$ from this way of partitioning 6 pizzas?

Comment: @James; your method implies at least one of the middle pizza type. We have 8 objects in total - 6 pizzas and 2 dividers, we can arrange these $\binom82$ ways.

Comment: ah yes! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This question boils down to counting in how many ways 3 numbers can sum to 6.
Let $x/y/z$ represent an order of $x$ margarita, $y$ pepperoni and $z$ prosciutto.
Then $0/0/6$ is valid and counts three times, $1/5/0$ can be counted 6 times (put the 5 in 3 different positions, and for each position the 1 and 0 can be switched), $2/4/0$ counts 6 times, $3/3/0$ counts three times, $1/1/4$ counts 3 times, $2/2/2$ counts just once, $2/3/1$ counts 6 times as well. Summing up gives you 28.